# How do I get the DOMDocument to process in PHP post-javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, tags, domdocument

I am writing a program to search  tags, however I can't get these if they are created with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this when it comes to Javascript because it needs a browser to be executed.

**Possible Solution**

You can run a headless browser with Selenium for example and wait for your DOM elements to be created then - and using Javascript - make a request to your PHP server with the `window.document.querySelector('html')` data that you want to parse.